# One-to-many relationship

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I have the following situation and I do not know how to solve it. I have tried in different ways but with no avail.I don't even know if this is possible. I would like this to be done with a CouchDB View, with a map(or reduce) functions.  I want to implement a one to many relationship in CouchDB as per the below example:

```
{
      "_id": 1,
      "name" : "Me",
      "doctype" : "employee"
    },
    {
     "_id" : 2,
     "name" : "MeAgain",
     "doctype" : "employee"
    }, 
    {
     "_id" : 3,
     "doctype": "holidayrequest",
     "startdate": "01/25/2021",
     "requesterid": "1"
    },
    {
     "_id" : 4,
     "doctype": "holidayrequest",
     "startdate": "01/16/2021",
     "requesterid": "1"
    },
    {
     "_id" : 5,
     "doctype": "holidayrequest",
     "startdate": "04/16/2021",
     "requesterid": "2"
    },
    {
     "_id" : 6,
     "doctype": "holidayrequest",
     "startdate": "04/25/2021",
     "requesterid": "2"
    }
```

I would like the outcome to be :

```
{
 "_id": 1,
  "name" : "Me",
  "doctype" : "employee",
  "holidays":[
     {
        "_id" : 3,
        "doctype": "holidayrequest",
        "startdate": "01/25/2021",
        "requesterid": "1"
     },
     {
        "_id" : 4,
        "doctype": "holidayrequest",
        "startdate": "01/16/2021",
        "requesterid": "1"
     }
  ]
},
{
 "_id" : 2,
 "name" : "MeAgain",
 "doctype" : "employee",
 "holidays":[
     {
      "_id" : 5,
      "doctype": "holidayrequest",
      "startdate": "04/16/2021",
      "requesterid": "2"
    },
    {
      "_id" : 6,
      "doctype": "holidayrequest",
      "startdate": "04/25/2021",
      "requesterid": "2"
    }
 ] 
}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Likely.  What have you tried? For example, show your code attempt.

Comment: Code in comments is completely unreadable.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is how website editor saved it.
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
function (doc) {
  if(doc.doctype==='users'){
    emit(doc._id,doc.name);
  }
  if(doc.doctype==='holidayrequests'){
    emit(doc.requesterid,doc);
  }
}
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Emitting a doc id as a key and storing a doc as a view value is a needless and costly redundancy as both may produced from a view result (if desired).  Think through emitting `doctype`, `name` and `requestorid` in some combination to form keys or  directly as values.